Soil moisture mean per pixel, per year, for a whole country
I am trying to calculate the soil moisture (mean per pixel, sm_surface) for Somalia using the SMAP Level-4 Dataset for the year 2019. The session crashes (user memory limit exceeded) when I run my script. Other scripts work, so I think that it is not an issue related to the user memory.
code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f16654896f1aa192d63b0ee0b3b1276e
// Load a Feature Collection
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');

// Filter for Somalia
var roi = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Somalia'));

// Load SMAP Data
var smap = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/SMAP/SPL4SMGP/007');

// Define the year
var year = 2019;
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);
var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'year');

// Filter SMAP Data by Date and Select the 'sm_surface' Band
var filtered = smap.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate)).select('sm_surface');

// Calculate Mean Soil Moisture
var meanSoilMoisture = filtered.mean().rename('mean_soil_moisture');

// Visualization Parameters
var palette = ['blue', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'];
var visParams = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.9,
  palette: palette
};

// Calculate Regional Statistics
var stats = meanSoilMoisture.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: roi,
  scale: 11000,
});

// Print the mean soil moisture value to the console
print('Mean Soil Moisture for Somalia in 2019:', stats.get('mean_soil_moisture'));

// Clip the image to the country boundary and display
var meanSoilMoistureSomalia = meanSoilMoisture.clip(roi);
Map.addLayer(meanSoilMoistureSomalia, visParams, 'Mean Soil Moisture (Somalia)');

// Center the map on Somalia
Map.centerObject(roi, 6);

// Export the image to Google Drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: meanSoilMoistureSomalia,
  description: 'MeanSoilMoisture_Somalia_2019',
  folder: 'EarthEngineExports',
  fileNamePrefix: 'MeanSoilMoisture_Somalia_2019',
  region: roi.geometry().bounds(),
  scale: 11000,  // Set scale to 11,000 meters (11 km) to match SMAP resolution
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',  // Coordinate Reference System
  maxPixels: 1e13    // Increase the max pixels if needed
});


For me runs maximum 9 months. For 1 year is too much data. Try another method, like mean by month and then by year.
